# cygwin file command not detecting mpg?

Tags: command-line, cygwin

I have noticed that the file command in linux, is detecting this mpg as data?

http://www.berkut13.com/videos/brakeup.mpg

it detects flv ok but this mpg file it doesn't..

i'd like to be able to detect mpg files.

I found the part of the magic file for MPEG..

```
#                       MPEG file
# MPEG sequences
# FIXME: This section is from the old magic.mime file and needs integrating with the rest
0       belong             0x000001BA
>4      byte               &0x40
!:mime  video/mp2p
>4      byte               ^0x40
!:mime  video/mpeg
0       belong             0x000001BB
!:mime  video/mpeg
0       belong             0x000001B0
!:mime  video/mp4v-es
0       belong             0x000001B5
!:mime  video/mp4v-es
0       belong             0x000001B3
!:mime  video/mpv
0       belong&0xFF5FFF1F  0x47400010
!:mime  video/mp2t
0       belong             0x00000001
>4      byte&0x1F      0x07
!:mime  video/h264
```

and the file

```
$ xxd -p brakeup.mpg | head -n 1
000001ba2100010001800e3b000001bb000c800e3b07e1ffc0c020e0e02e

$ od -x brakeup.mpg | head -n 2
0000000 0000 ba01 0021 0001 8001 3b0e 0000 bb01
0000020 0c00 0e80 073b ffe1 c0c0 e020 2ee0 0000
```

Comment: It's a restricted format so it's not surprising that Linux handles it awkwardly. Do you have the w32codecs package and ffmpeg properly installed?

Comment: Works fine here. `$ file brakeup.mpg` `brakeup.mpg: MPEG sequence, v1, system multiplex`

Comment: here's the magic file  http://www.sendspace.com/file/i0qu6h I remember now it was cygwin, i've updated title and tags.

Answer (score 2):

The `file` command uses a list of file definitions in a **magic** file (usually /usr/share/file/magic on linux systems, or /etc/magic on Unix).

Most of the entries in that file are just 'magic' numbers: the file command matches the first few bytes of a file against these entries to identify the file.

Try adding these definitions from this [example magic file](http://www.garykessler.net/library/magic.html):

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# animation:  file(1) magic for animation/movie formats
#
# animation formats
# MPEG, FLI, DL originally from vax@ccwf.cc.utexas.edu (VaX#n8)
# FLC, SGI, Apple originally from Daniel Quinlan (quinlan@yggdrasil.com)

# MPEG animation format
0   belong      0x000001b3      MPEG video stream data
#>4 beshort&0xfff0  x           (%d x
#>5 beshort&0x0fff  x           %d)
0   belong      0x000001ba      MPEG system stream data
```

Your brakeup.mpg file begins with `00,00,01,ba` so the file command should identify it as MPEG system data at least.

On Ubuntu-based linux distributions, the /usr/share/file/magic already has definitions that will identify that MPG file as:

```
brakeup.mpg: MPEG sequence, v1, system multiplex
```

Comment: thanks, i've just updated my question adding a comment linking to my magic file

Comment: +1 for finding that line.. my magic file has  0x000001BA but also it says "# FIXME: This section is from the old magic.mime file and needs integrating with the rest " It may be more like the BSD version 'cos man file says BSD manual. and it reports as 5.5

Comment: `file` is a BSD command, and I think you mean 5.05.

Comment: @Ignacio yes you're right, 5.05